# Chrome Debugger: Is there a way searching a specific key within an object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I console.log a large, very nested object on to the console of the Chrome Debugger like here ...

[image]

**Is there a way to search for a specific key (e.g. UserId) which might be exist somewhere within the object?**

Comment: I think you can modify this: [How to search the browser window object looking which object or variable has the searched-for value?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46536947). Depending on what you need to do next, you can also simply search in JSON.stringify() using a regexp, for example.

Comment: If you want to do this with a script, depending on how the data is structured, it might be worth looking into either of the [breadth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)- or [depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)-first search algorithms, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type <kbd>Control-f</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd-f</kbd> on Mac) then the keyword to search the console for the keyword.

Comment: That only works for visible properties, not the collapsed ones.